# Что не так с моим кодом?

Tags: python

есть задача:

Дано число n
Ваша задача — найти число из n цифр, каждая из которых равна 1 или 2, которое делится на 2^n, или сказать, что такого числа не существует.

Тест 1:
входные данные:
1
выходные данные:
2

Тест 2:
входные данные:
2
выходные данные:
12

мой код:

```
def check(number):
    while number > 0:
        if (0 < number % 10 < 3):
            number //= 10
        else:
            return False
    return True
 
 
n = int(input())
 
template = 2 ** n
number = template
 
while True:
    if (check(number)):
        print(number)
        break
    number += template
```

**что не так?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получился так:

```
n = int(input())

if n == 0:
    print("Нет числа")
    exit()

s = ''
for i in range(n):
    if int("1" + s) % (2 << i) == 0:
        s = "1" + s
    else:
        s = "2" + s
    
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
from itertools import product

digits = ['1', '2']
n = int(input())
if n < 1:
    print('Нет числа')
    exit()

temp = 2**n
for prod in product(digits, repeat=n):
    number = int(''.join(prod))
    if number % temp == 0:
        print(number)
        break
else:
    print('Нет числа')
```

Так должно быть немного быстрее (не проверяет нечетные числа):

```
for prod in product(digits, repeat=n-1): # <--------
    number = int(''.join(prod) + '2')    # <--------
    if number % temp == 0:
        print(number)
        break
else:
    print('Нет числа')
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы совершенно не то делали

```
# получить кол-во цифр в числе
digits_count = int(input())

# перебрать все соответствующие числа
res = []

for i in range(10**(digits_count - 1), 10**digits_count - 1):
    # рассматривать только числа, которые делятся на 2^n
    if i % 2**digits_count == 0:
        # определить, содержит ли число цифры отличные от 1 и 2
        value = i
        is_success = True

        while value != 0:
            digit = value % 10
            value //= 10
            if digit != 1 and digit != 2:
                is_success = False
                break

        # добавить найденное число в список
        if is_success is True:
            res.append(i)

# вывести результат
if len(res) == 0:
    print("Нет числа")
else:
    print(*res, sep='\n')
```

если работать со строками, то можно сделать проверку попроще:

```
for i in range(10**(digits_count - 1), 10**digits_count - 1):
    # рассматривать только числа, которые делятся на 2^n
    if i % 2**digits_count == 0:
        # определить, содержит ли число цифры отличные от 1 и 2
        digits = list(filter(lambda i: i != '1' and i != '2', set(str(i))))

        # добавить найденное число в список
        if len(digits) == 0:
            res.append(i)
```

можно ускорить в 3 раза код если уменьшить цикл от 1xxxxx до 2xxxxx

```
for i in range(10**(digits_count - 1), 3 * 10**(digits_count - 1)):
    # рассматривать только числа, которые делятся на 2^n
    # определить, содержит ли число цифры отличные от 1 и 2
    if i % 2**digits_count == 0 and len(list(filter(lambda i: i != '1' and i != '2', set(str(i))))) == 0:
        # добавить найденное число в список
        if len(list(filter(lambda i: i != '1' and i != '2', set(str(i))))) == 0:
            res.append(i)
```

можно еще существенно увеличить скорость, если просматривать только числа, которые делятся на `2^n` через модификацию `for` и указания шага в `2^n`

в этом случае скорость возрастает так же еще в разы и порядки (в зависимости от кол-ва цифр) + можно улучшить проверку на цифры (от @Danis):

```
import math

# получить кол-во цифр в числе
digits_count = int(input())

if digits_count < 1:
    print("Нет числа")
    exit()

limit = 2**digits_count

start = math.ceil(10**(digits_count - 1) / limit) * limit

# перебрать все соответствующие числа
res = []

for i in range(start, 3 * 10**(digits_count - 1), limit):
    # определить, содержит ли число цифры отличные от 1 и 2
    if len(list(filter(lambda i: i != '1' and i != '2', set(str(i))))) == 0:
        # добавить найденное число в список
        if len(set(str(i) + '12')) == 2:
            res.append(i)

# вывести результат
if len(res) == 0:
    print("Нет числа")
else:
    print(*res, sep='\n')
```

Comment: думаю, что лучше до `for` проверить корректность ввода на всякий случай. `digits_count > 0`. да и сохранить `2**digits_count` в переменную, чтобы не считать заново

Comment: Всё работает отлично, но можно го сделать как то побыстрее? Может на другом языке или?

Comment: @n1tr0xs, да, разумно

Comment: Нет :( Всё равно выводит что слишком медленно(

Comment: место `len(list(filter(lambda i: i != '1' and i != '2', set(str(i))))) == 0:` можно сделать так: `len(set(str(i) + "01")) == 2`

Comment: у вас в обоих `if` происходит одно и тоже, поэтому от одного из них можно избавиться

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9494887/14227417

Comment: @Daniel Developer, есть очень быстрый способ - максимально быстрое решение вашей задачи - надо просто работать в двоичной системе `1` `2` от числа `11...11` до числа `22..22` несложно подсчитать, что тогда вам всего несколько десятков проверок надо делать, а не миллионы (при больших числах), как именно реализовать такой перебор - это уже на ваш вкус - формировать из списка, формировать из бинарного представления и т.д., максимально быстро - формировать из списка